# Windows Storage Server 2003: Shadow Copy (VSS) enabled for volume, but Previous Version not visible on the server

Tags: windows-server-2003, vss

Windows Storage Server 2003
We have Shadow Copy (VSS) enabled for one volume.

However Previous Version tab is not visible on the server on properties dialogs on any file or folder on that volume.

We don't want this tab to be visible on the clients, just on the server.

I've checked the VSS settings and they're definitly enabled for the volume.

I'm stuck!

Do I have to install the client-software on the server? The folder
\%systemroot%\system32\clients\twclient 
contains 3 empty subdirs (location copies from docs)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the Shadow Copy Client on a client(XP) system for Server 2003 based VSS.  Windows 7 clients should have it installed by default.  I do not believe you can see them from the server (as odd as it sounds).  Server 2K8 R2 you can see them on the server :)

Comment: It is weird, but I confirmed this. We have several Server 2K8 servers and they have the client installed.
Though, I could find the Shadow Copy Client, don't need it, it works...

Answer (score 1):

from the server itself have you tried \\servername\sharename\   then right click on the folder your trying to restore then look at the previous versions?

if you want you can add the previous version client to your workstations then do the above if you want to do it remotely!

Comment: This matches my experience. F:\something\ doesn't have a Previous Versions tab, but \\servername\f$\something\ does when accessed from the server.